# Quick question on ideal gas law

Tags: pressure, sun, ideal-gas, neutron-stars

[image]

I know that the ideal gas law is: $$P = nkT$$

So Pressure = Number of Particles per unit volume * kT

Why is the number of particles per unit volume = $\frac{\rho}{\mu M_H}$?

Shouldn't it simply be $\frac{\rho}{M_H}$ since its (Mass per unit volume)/(mass per particle).

Comment: What are the units of $\rho$? Is it an energy density, mass density, number density (...)?

Comment: it's density - mass per unit volume

Comment: It appears that $\rho/\mu$ would be the 'average' particle number density (at radius $r$). The $1/M_H$ is strange... I suggest you check the first equation on your slide since the units don't seem to be correct. Remember, pressure is force per area.

Comment: The $\mu = \frac{1}{2}$ is dimensionless

Comment: Are you sure you know what the ideal gas law is?

Comment: @Weasel OP is using non-standard notation in which $n$ is actually a particle density, so the ideal gas law as he stated is OK.

Comment: Disagree - this is exactly the notation I use/am use to.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it. I know why $\mu = \frac{1}{2}$.

Firstly, $\mu$ is defined as the mean molecular weight, $\mu = \frac{\bar m}{m_H}$ which can be understood as the average nucleon number per particle. $\frac{1}{\mu}$ can be understood as number of particles per nucleon. A quick analysis of fully ionised hydrogen gives $\frac{1}{\mu} = 2$ (1 proton, 1 electron). But we are not satisfied till we truly understand the underpinnings of this equation, right? Let's see how $\mu$ is calculated in general below:

For a neutral gas:

$$\bar m = \mu m_H = \frac{\sum_j N_jm_j}{\sum_j N_j} $$

$$\frac{1}{\mu m_H} =\frac{\sum_j N_j}{\sum_j N_j m_j}  = \frac{Total \space Number \space of \space particles }{Total \space Mass \space of\space particles}       $$

Usually we are given the mass fraction $X_j$ of the $j^{th}$ particle, so let's try to incorporate that in our solution.

$$=\sum_j  \frac{Number \space of \space type \space j \space particles}{Mass \space of \space type \space j \space particles} \times  \frac{Mass \space of \space type \space j \space particles}{Total \space Mass \space of\space particles} $$

$$=\sum_j \frac{N_j}{N_j A_j m_H} \times X_j $$
$$ \frac{1}{\mu m_H} = \sum_j \frac{X_j}{A_j m_H} $$

where $A_j$ gives the nucleon number of type j particle.

Thus for neutral particles,

$$\frac{1}{\mu} = \sum_j \frac{X_j}{A_j} $$

However for fully ionised particles, now there are electrons stripped from the nucleus, so we would expect the average number per particles per nucleon $(\frac{1}{\mu})$ to increase.

We have the number of stripped electrons equal to the atomic (proton) number:

$$\frac{1}{\mu} = \sum_j \frac{1 + Z_j}{A_j} X_j $$

For a star that's composed of ionised hydrogen, $Z_j = 1$, $A_j = 1$, $X_j = 1$ so $\frac{1}{\mu} = 2$